# WOL works over internet for couple of seconds

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan, static-ip

I have 2 internet connections (ISP1 and ISP2) to my PC with a WiFi adapter and a wired NIC. I have a network of PCs connected to the NIC. I have a public static IP to the ISP2 router connected to the NIC. With depicus windows WOL app, I am able to switch on my Servers connected  to ISP2 from my PC which is connected to both ISP1 and ISP2. This is fine and expected.

I was doing trial and error to use WOL over internet by disconnecting the ISP2 cable from my PC which still has internet from ISP1. Immediately after disconnecting the ISP2 LAN cable from PC, I was still able to switch on the Servers under ISP2 with the WOL app from PC. May be because I was able to see the Network connection for few seconds even after disconnecting. But could not do it again later after some time. Looks like the PC had the ISP2 LAN connection settings and public static IP in memory for few seconds. Is it correct?
Looks like WOL worked over internet for couple of seconds. Any idea how it worked?

If that is the case, then can we switch on a PC over internet if we can some how tweak and make the IP of source PC to be that of target public static IP. It may be not legal to tweak an IP, but is it still possible?

Diagram of the PCs over 2 connections

[image]

Comment: I've read this three times - I still don't know what you mean.

Comment: The network does not disconnect immediately after unplugging the network cable. Is it due to network details persisted in memory?

Comment: It doesn't really matter - if there's no cable present, nothing is going to get through. What you may be seeing is a redirect over WiFi.

Comment: WOL would not have worked immediately after unplugging, but it did work because I still had internet over another WiFi  connection.

Comment: Yes, it might be a redirect over WiFi, but it worked only for the duration which the LAN connection was visible after unplugging the LAN cable.

Comment: If there's no wire connected no signal is getting through it, unless you believe in ghosts. The explanation lies elsewhere.

Comment: My intention is to understand how WOL worked over internet?

Comment: Then you may have to clarify your question. As it stands, it's unfathomable.

Comment: @Tetsujin please have a look at the Diagram in the link to avoid confusion.

Comment: Please use integrated function to add the picture, not an external link. So text and pic can be displayed at the same time. There is probable some work necessary on the text as well, but let's start with the pic.

Comment: I need at least 10 reputation to add image with integrated function.

Comment: I inlined the image. I'm stil no wiser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question**s**:

First question: No, if you disconnect the cable you can not use WOL or anything else on the disconnected NIC. In order for the magic packet to reach the "cable NIC" (I assume you used the MAC of the cable NIC for the WOL) through the WLAN-adapter there must be a non standard setup. You WLAN-AP doesn't not the MAC of your wired NIC so it would know send the packet "through the WLAN-adapter to the wired NIC" assuming a standard setup).

Second question: No, you can not just manually give your NIC a public IP address and access it over the internet. That is not how the internet works.

Greater chances are you have (unknowingly) other "wakeup options" enabled, and they caused the system to wake up.

Comment: You misunderstood my first question. I agree  WOL will not work after cable unplugged. But I still can ping the target public IP through my WiFi. So I am trying to understand, how WOL worked over internet?

Comment: @Mahen see updates/additions to the answer...

Comment: But WOL over internet works for couple of seconds till which the LAN connection is visible even after unplugging the cable.   So I could not understand what type of non-standard setup exists for those couple of seconds?

Comment: @Mahen that non "standard-setup" which would responsible to "forward" the magic packet to your wired NIC would be permanent, not just a "couple of seconds". But again this would be a very unusual setup, not even sure how I would do that, since the WLAN-NIC will go to sleep as well. No, I still don't think the magic packet caused the wake, especially if it was a "one time thing". This is not how "networks work".

Comment: Why will wireless LAN go to sleep when I unplug the wired LAN?   I believe its not true, bcoz I did not disturb the wireless LAN and internet still works.

Comment: @Mahen If the PC woke up (in your words "switched on"), it must have been "asleep" (at least S3 power state). If the PC is "asleep" the WLAN-NIC gets turned off. Otherwise the question does not make any sense to me. WOL does not work on WLAN. Unless there is some freaky HW out there I don't know about...

Comment: I think you got my picture wrong. WOL is running on a PC which is connected to a WiFi and a Wired NIC. This Wired NIC is in the network of target PC which is switched off. So I mean when the Wired NIC is disconnected from the PC where I run WOL, WiFi internet still exists.   WiFi connection has no link with the Wired connection. Both are standalone internet connections from different ISP providers.

Comment: @Mahen maybe you could add a diagram and rewrite your question complimenting the diagram to make it easier to understand. Same as Tetsujin I'm a little clueless here...

Comment: Yes, I will do that so that it avoids confusion.

Comment: Sorry, it asks for at least 10 reputation to upload image.

Comment: Here u go, image link https://freeimage.host/i/2G8M57

Comment: @Mahen sorry, didn't notice your update, is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes. The same thing does not reproduce now .

Comment: Now I am checking if Depicus's. WOL app will work over internet as claimed by them. But it does not work. Not sure why they claim so and why they gave an option for internet also apart from LAN in their windows WOL exe.

Comment: WOL over internet can work but not "directly" between PC2<-- internet ->PC1 (sleeping). But you'll need an additional "waking device" (e.g. another PC) that can be reach over the Internet and does "the waking" on the LAN like this: PC2<-- internet ->WakingDevice<-LAN->PC1 (sleeping). But I would suggest to start a new question for that.

Comment: Yes, I did find such a way where people are using a raspberry pi as the waking device.